# Date difference not calculating correctly in php

Tags: php, wordpress, date, difference

I am using the following code to get the difference between two dates. I'm having issues with it returning the correct amount of days left.

```
<?php 
$nextservicedate = FrmProDisplaysController::get_shortcode( array( 'id' => 3451 ) );
$currentdate = date("d/m/Y");
$daysremaining = $nextservicedate - $currentdate;
echo $nextservicedate. " | ";
    if ( strpos($nextservicedate, 'None registered') !== false )

    {
        echo "None Registered";
    }
    elseif ($daysremaining < "0")
    {
        $negativedays = str_replace('-', ' ', $daysremaining);
        echo $negativedays. " days overdue";
    }
    elseif ($daysremaining <= "30")
    {
        echo $daysremaining. " days (upcoming service)";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $daysremaining. " days";
    }
?>
```

The entry

```
FrmProDisplaysController::get_shortcode( array( 'id' => 3451 ) )
```

returns a date from a wordpress form plugin (FormidablePro) as 30/10/2016.

The code is returning there are 23 days remaining which I believe is taking it to the end of this month.

I know I'm missing something and think it probably has something to do with the working out the days remaining part of the code.

Can anyone see any glaring errors? Do I need to declare the $nextservicedate like I've done with $currentdate?

Any help would be greatly recieved!

Regards

Matt

Comment: Give us your both dates !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns date string which cannot be used to perform arithmetic operations on date.

What you need to do is create `DateTime` object of service date from String using [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and create current `DateTime()` object.

Then use [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function of `DateTime` object to find the difference between two days.

So your code would look something like this,

```
$nextservicedate=DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y",$nextservicedate);
$todaydate=new DateTime();
$difference=$nextservicedate->diff($todaydate);
```

To get the difference in days,

```
echo $difference->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Thanks @alok Patel